# google colab errors - can't open anything

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I was using Google Colab to do some python practice. I have quite a few notebooks with homework and notes in them. All of sudden I can't save anything or even open a notebook I saved earlier. These are the errors I get.

```
Notebook loading error
There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.
Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0

Error

Unable to load Colaboratory.
A network error occurred and the request could not be completed.
GapiError: A network error occurred and the request could not be completed.
    at GG.hy [as constructor] (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:1345:363)
    at new GG (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:1564:363)
    at za.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:1652:331)
    at Ba (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:509:336)
    at za.throw_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:508:402)
    at Da.throw (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:510:248)
    at c (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:519:79)
```

I've disabled all extensions, logged out, deleted cookies, tried incognito, tried sharing and using another account but still can't download any notebook, restarted runtime. I can't even create a new notebook without the first error happening. It happens in any google account I try.

I'm out of ideas and tried anything I've found on here that pertains to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an ongoing outage for Google services like Drive and Gmail. Colab appears impacted as well. Details and status:

https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=4&iid=082ee9e7a232740761ef507d7ac31eb2

Comment: yup, just got that message now when loading. thanks!